# How to delete registry strings in specified key if string contains value?

Tags: string, batch-file, cmd, key, regedit

I have a generic registry key that has various strings dumped in it by programs:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Folders`

How can I use a batch file to read the strings in the key, and if a string contains the word 'example' as part of the name, I want it to be deleted.

Comment: This sounds kind of dangerous - just saying.

Comment: Duely noted, still would like an answer if possible.

Comment: You mention "batch file", are you referring to .BAT, .CMD, or a powershell script?

Comment: Ideally .BAT as that is what I've been writing other commands in. Not familiar with the other two unfortunately. I necessary I may just write this in C#, but was hoping I could do it in a .bat so a couple other people could see the source.

Comment: FWIW, if your target OS is Windows, you should consider using .CMD.  Very simlar to DOS .BAT but more features are available to to person writing the script.

Comment: Look at `reg delete /?` for help.

Comment: I found this on StackOverflow regarding modifying registry entries from a command-line.  This may prove useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130193/is-it-possible-to-modify-a-registry-entry-via-a-bat-cmd-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
SET "key=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Folders"
SET "search=example"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('reg query "%key%" ^| find "%search%"') DO REG delete "%key%" /v "%%~a"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however it is not removing my strings that have that as part of the name value.

Comment: What strings are not removed? Can you show examples, please. Do you get error messages?

Comment: `%%a` is going to include the `    REG_SZ    1` etc at the end and will not remove the value.

Comment: Yes, this is above XP not easy to remove. XP uses `\t` between the key and `REG_SZ...`, Vista and later `spaces`.