# How to install BHO without Wix in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, bho

I followed this link [How to get started with developing Internet Explorer extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/how-to-get-started-with-developing-internet-explorer-extensions) and after following it I got it to install on my own machine by using the Debug mode on Visual Studio. How do I install it on another users machine without them having to start up Visual Studio and run through Debug?

Answer (score 2):

If you have have followed the link posted in the answer (making sure you have the register and unregister methods) then you can create a batch file that people can use to install it on their own machines.

Ex:
`"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\gacutil.exe" /f /i "%~dp0YourDLL.dll"
"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" /unregister "%~dp0YourDLL.dll"
"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" "%~dp0YourDLL.dll"
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe" /f /i "%~dp0YourDLL.dll"
"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" /unregister "%~dp0YourDLL.dll"
"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" "%~dp0YourDLL.dll"`

REG ADD "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Extensions{0A0F07FC-0099-4AAF-8D2F-C6C710EE91CA}" /v "Icon" /t REG_SZ /d "%~dp0Resources\YourIcon.ico" /f
REG ADD "HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Extensions{0A0F07FC-0099-4AAF-8D2F-C6C710EE91CA}" /v "Icon" /t REG_SZ /d "%~dp0Resources\YourIcon.ico" /f

You do not have to include the REG ADD at the end if you don't have an Icon that you want to use but I couldn't find a way to have a dynamic path for the icon in Visual Studio that would work so I decided to register it through the batch file itself. If you want info on registry commands for batch files you can look here: [Is it possible to modify a registry entry via a .bat/.cmd script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130193/is-it-possible-to-modify-a-registry-entry-via-a-bat-cmd-script).

The %~dp0 before the YourDLL in the first part of the code is to get the current path that your batch file is located in. I found that information out through this [How do I find the current directory of a batch file, and then use it for the path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255184/how-do-i-find-the-current-directory-of-a-batch-file-and-then-use-it-for-the-pat)